# Possible disk IO problem. Help to be sure.

Tags: hard-drive, io

Since some time days ago, one of my servers started crashing. Currently it is crashing almost every day. Sometimes, over once a day. Only a restart can solve.

The last time the problem happend, the Server Load was over 1.000, but the server was not slow, But I could not access websites that make requests to mysql.

According to the command **iostat -dx 1** there was no data being written to the disks. That's is not normal. Some websites on the server demands a lot of data writing. So all that I can imagine is a disk problem.

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00    28.00  0.00 67.00     0.00   760.00    11.34     0.17    2.46   0.04   0.30
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00    28.00  0.00 67.00     0.00   760.00    11.34     0.17    2.46   0.04   0.30
sda3              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00   665.00  0.00 47.00     0.00  5696.00   121.19     0.24    5.15   0.17   0.80
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00   665.00  0.00 47.00     0.00  5696.00   121.19     0.24    5.15   0.17   0.80
sda3              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda3              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00

Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s   r/s   w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda1              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda2              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sda3              0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00  0.00  0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

I analyzed the **iostat** data for some seconds, and the %util value did not change over 0,80% any time. What is not normal, due to the websites that I host.

When the server is working fine SDA and SDA2 %util values area almost all the time over 30%

And this is top command data, while the server was facing problems: Notice that 97.1%sy is a very high value.

```
top - 15:47:05 up 1 day, 17:14,  1 user,  load average: 1492.16, 979.45, 435.51
Tasks: 1808 total, 1501 running, 307 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  2.9%us, 97.1%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  12290048k total, 12194552k used,    95496k free,   804172k buffers
Swap:  1052248k total,     5092k used,  1047156k free,  8652196k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                            
 8795 nobody    25   0  205m 8344 2176 R  2.0  0.1   0:05.43 httpd                                                              
 9039 nobody    25   0  205m 8344 2176 R  2.0  0.1   0:04.45 httpd                                                              
10529 root      15   0 14076 2436  820 R  2.0  0.0   0:00.23 top                                                                
 7995 nobody    21   0  213m  16m 7220 R  1.6  0.1   0:06.03 httpd                                                              
 8044 nobody    20   0  206m  12m 5024 R  1.6  0.1   0:03.66 httpd                                                              
 8491 nobody    25   0  210m  16m 6772 R  1.6  0.1   0:05.45 httpd                                                              
 8492 nobody    21   0  210m  15m 6240 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.56 httpd                                                              
 8737 nobody    25   0  205m 9640 3380 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.78 httpd                                                              
 8767 nobody    25   0  205m 8344 2176 R  1.6  0.1   0:05.02 httpd                                                              
 8776 nobody    25   0  205m 8452 2264 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.98 httpd                                                              
 8779 nobody    25   0  205m 8520 2340 R  1.6  0.1   0:05.05 httpd                                                              
 8815 nobody    25   0  205m 8452 2272 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.89 httpd                                                              
 8818 nobody    25   0  205m 8456 2276 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.66 httpd                                                              
 8836 nobody    25   0  205m 8444 2272 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.65 httpd                                                              
 8846 nobody    25   0  205m 8428 2240 R  1.6  0.1   0:04.49 httpd                                                              
 8854 nobody    25   0  205m 8376 2200 R  1.6  0.1   0:03.61 httpd                                                              
 8886 nobody    25   0  205m 8344 2176 R  1.6  0.1   0:03.09 httpd
```

I already restarted it, and now it's working fine, but this problem is hapenning over and over....

My disks are in RAID. According to these logs, is it really a disk problem?

Comment: What Linux version and distribution are you running?

Comment: On what hardware is running the server? What type of disk controller?

Comment: Pleas add the output of the last `dmesg` messages.

Comment: dmesg doesn't show any disk error.

Comment: please provide the output of 'df -h'.

Answer (score 1):

Check your RAID controller status to see the health of the disks. Use `strace` on the most I/O intensive threads and see what they are doing. List also all the file descriptors for that process with `ls -l /proc/<PID>/fd` and try to find out which file is writing.

Use [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/) with `topio` option to find the process that is most I/O expansive. Or you can use [iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/)

You can investigate further with `systemtap` to see if it is a FS, disk/controller or user space problem.

Comment: dtrace and topio "command not found"

Comment: Sorry, I mean dstat. You have to install it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have given here are no logs. You only provide server status.

So from you "logs" it looks clean, but this is neither a proof nor a counterproof. Check with disk checking tools, look at the SMART information, watch out for I/O errors or whatever. But don't think that a `top` output shows disk errors!

**Important:** Look out for professional help. You asked 18 questions and 8 of them are about the same problem. You provide no information, accept no answer and only rephrase the same question with other words and always blame another culprit.

Comment: I think that the system is using a RAIC controller. So you can not use SMART in this case. You need to use the tools provided by the controller manufacturer.

Comment: @MirceaVutcovici However. This is not the problem. The only problem the OP has is to analyze the problem and wants us to analyze it remotely without giving appropriate information. See the other questions.